# How do i make my chrome extension identify a specific file type on a page and download it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would like to make my Google Chrome Extension identify a specific file type (i.e .mp4) on a page then download it. Ideally i would like to be able to paste a url into the extension and have it open up the page in a tab find the file, add it to downloads and then close the tab.

thank you for any help you can give me

Liam

Comment: mp4's are usually in `<video>` tags, possibly in `<source>` tags inside the `<video>` tag if the `<video>` tag has no `src` attribute

Comment: That's broad... In which case would these files appear on the target pages? Are you only interested in the ones loaded before page's load? The ones loaded dynamically? The ones only requested or all could-be requested (we can ask video elements to wait for user's action before starting downloading the media). Should this take into account framed documents (a lot of video services use iframes to display their videos)? Do you want to target only the requests made by the browser (one could load a video through xhr and display it only with MSE, making video element targeting useless).